# MVC4 - Just 1 of my controllers (Reports) is causing a browser popup asking for username and password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have about 10 controllers in my site, they all have the same authorization, [Authorize(Roles = "RoleName")], they all work fine except for one. When I try to browse to an action within that controller, I get this browser popup:

[image]

I've tried my windows password and website password with no success.

I've checked windows security settings for all files in the site and I've given full permission to NetworkService and even Everyone, and I still get the popup.

The controller is called Reports if that helps at all?

Comment: Are you using reporting services? Maybe it's asking for credentials do authenticate on SSRS not on your MVC site.

Comment: Wow, uninstalling Reporting Services fixed the problem. Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: no problems Owen, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using reporting services? Maybe it's asking for credentials do authenticate on SSRS not on your MVC site.